# modenizr complete not executing when already loaded files load again

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am using modenizr to load the js and css files after loading the files i have to do some function. So on complete of modenizr i wrote the code. The problem is when first time the files loaded it executes the complete but if load the file that already loaded it is not executing the complete.Help me to sort out the problem

My code is given below

```
function loadFilesAndExecuteCallback(files, callback) {                                     

Modernizr.load({
    load : files,
    complete : function() {

        callback();
    }
});
}
```